# How to install android code into mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator

Basically i dont know the mobile file / setup exe extension and all ,

Now i did some basic sample, it working fine in my simulator,

Before i proceed , i want to test these codes in my mobile , the code working or not,

What should i do now ,

I want to install my sample application into my iphone, how to install this application,

Please guide me ,

Thanks

Comment: "iphone"? Is that a typo?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iPhone is a typo..then you should have a look at [Developing on a Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

> If using Eclipse, run or debug as usual. You will be presented with a Device Chooser dialog that lists the available emulator(s) and connected device(s). Select the device upon which you want to install and run the application.
>
> If using the Android Debug Bridge
>   (adb), you can issue commands with the
>   -d flag to target your connected device.

Answer (score 0):

First install Android on your iPhone: http://www.taranfx.com/android-on-iphone

Than you can connect the phone via usb. Maybe you need to restart your adb-server but as soon as your device is listed by adb, you can chose the phone as a target in eclipse. Thats all you need... (this works with devices shipped with android, too)

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing an application for Android or Iphone?

**You cannot run an application that is developed for Android on Iphone OS directly. You require a device that has Android OS installed in it.**

Installing an apk is simple just plug in your device and install relevant device drivers. Under the list of devices you should be able to see your new device. Just right click on your project and click Run AS -->Android application and it should get your project installed on your device directly like on the stimualtor.

A simple google search will provide you more info on the same.

Comment: Then i should install eclips on iphone

Comment: Sorry i did not understand what you mean by "Install Eclipse on Iphone" and the context with respect to this question. Eclipse is an IDE and you cannot install it on Iphone